# I can't manage to create 3rd level of dijit.Tree

Tags: json, tree, dojo

I wanted to create a 3 level `dijit.Tree`, like that:

```
-root
|
--level1
 |
 --level2
```

I thought it would be really simple since there's a code snippet in [this tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Tree-examples.html#dijit-tree-examples) (example 1). But somehow I manage to fail. 
This is my dojo code (variable names are in Polish, I hope it's not a problem):

```
modelRaportow = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
    store: new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        url: "logika/getJSON/getStatusRaportow.php"
    }),
    query: {typ: 'galaz'},
    rootId: 'statusRaportuRoot',
    rootLabel: 'Status raportu',
    childrenAttrs: 'raporty'
});

drzewoRaportow = new dijit.Tree({
    openOnClick: true,
    model: modelRaportow,
    showRoot: true,
    persist: false
}, "target-status-raportow");

drzewoRaportow.startup();
```

This is my JSON returned by `logika/getJSON/getStatusRaportow.php` (again, names are in Polish):

```
{
    "identifier":"id",
    "label":"status",
    "items": [
        {"id":0,"status":"zaakceptowane","typ":"galaz"
            "raporty":[{"_reference":1},{"_reference":2},{"_reference":3}]},
                {"id":1,"data":"24-10-2011","wykonujacy":"cblajszczak","idKlienta":3,"status":"Raport0","typ":"lisc"},
                {"id":2,"data":"24-10-2011","wykonujacy":"cblajszczak","idKlienta":1,"status":"Raport1","typ":"lisc"},
                {"id":3,"data":"24-10-2011","wykonujacy":"cblajszczak","idKlienta":3,"status":"Raport2","typ":"lisc"},
        {"id":4,"status":"odrzucone","typ":"galaz"
            "raporty":[{"_reference":5},{"_reference":6},{"_reference":7}]},
                {"id":5,"data":"24-10-2011","wykonujacy":"cblajszczak","idKlienta":1,"status":"Raport3","typ":"lisc"},
                {"id":6,"data":"24-10-2011","wykonujacy":"cblajszczak","idKlienta":3,"status":"Raport4","typ":"lisc"},
                {"id":7,"data":"24-10-2011","wykonujacy":"cblajszczak","idKlienta":3,"status":"Raport5","typ":"lisc"}
]}
```

And finally, this is what I'm getting: [img](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/9/dijit.jpg/) - root node and lvl 1 nodes returned by query, no child nodes.

The question is - where is my mistake? Can anyone see it?

Comment: Just FYI [Dojo Unit Tests](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.1/dojo-release-1.6.1/dijit/tests/tree/test_Tree_DnD.html) are a great source for working examples.

Comment: thanks, it'll definitely help someday : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a partial answer:  by stepping through the code in a similar situation, I've discovered that it expects childrenAttrs to be an array, so it should be:

```
childrenAttrs: ['raporty']
```

but I still cannot get the third level to appear in my case.

Comment: Great.  My addition problem was missing the 

   openOnClick: true

Answer (score 4):

You have no comma between the `typ` and `raporty` value pair.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the problem has already been solved by John Y. JSON string is generated by `json_encode`, so missing comma is probably only my mistake during copying/formatting.